# How to sort linking objects of realm?

Tags: android, sorting, realm, rlmlinkingobjects

I have a realmObject that includes linkingObject.

```
@RealmClass
public class VolleyballPlayer extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    @LinkingObjects("volleyballPlayer")
    private final RealmResults<Player> players = null;
}

@RealmClass
public class Player extends RealmObject {

    private Set set;
    private VolleyballPlayer volleyballPlayer;
    private BasketballPlayer basketballPlayer;
    private String playerName = "";
}
```

I want to sort linking objects which inside realmObject. But the first query is running but other query is crashing because of that sorted linking objects.

```
     RealmResults<VolleyballPlayer> volleyballPlayers = 
   mRealm.where(VolleyballPlayer.class)
.findAll();

     RealmResults<VolleyballPlayer> volleyballPlayers = 
  mRealm.where(VolleyballPlayer.class)
.sort("link.playerName") 
.findAll();
```

My crash report:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Invalid query: field 'volleyballPlayer' in class 'VolleyballPlayer' is of invalid type 'LINKING_OBJECTS'.
                                                                              at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.verifyColumnType(FieldDescriptor.java:277)
                                                                              at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.verifyInternalColumnType(FieldDescriptor.java:230)
                                                                              at io.realm.internal.fields.CachedFieldDescriptor.compileFieldDescription(CachedFieldDescriptor.java:83)
                                                                              at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.compileIfNecessary(FieldDescriptor.java:285)
                                                                              at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.getFinalColumnType(FieldDescriptor.java:213)
                                                                              at io.realm.internal.SortDescriptor.checkFieldType(SortDescriptor.java:110)
                                                                              at io.realm.internal.SortDescriptor.getInstance(SortDescriptor.java:95)
                                                                              at io.realm.internal.SortDescriptor.getInstanceForSort(SortDescriptor.java:65)
                                                                              at io.realm.RealmQuery.sort(RealmQuery.java:1953)
                                                                              at io.realm.RealmQuery.sort(RealmQuery.java:1914)
                                                                              at io.realm.RealmQuery.sort(RealmQuery.java:1898)
                                                                              at com.android.android.dao.crud.ShareCRUD$1.run(ShareCRUD.java:40)
                                                                              at com.android.android.dao.RealmController$1.run(RealmController.java:60)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: `Player` doesn't have a field called `players`, I'd be amazed if your code doesn't give an error at compile time.

Comment: Oh sorry, I edit my answer

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Does realm support sorting in linking objects?

Comment: Apparently not, so I opened https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5683

Comment: But you can create the Query based on `Player` then just use `getVolleyballPlayer()`

Comment: thank you for your works

Comment: When class extends `RealmObject `, `@RealmClass` annotation is not required.

Comment: what should I do @VenomVendor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm isn't support sorting in linking objects. So I add `name` field to `VolleyballPlayer`.

```
@RealmClass
public class VolleyballPlayer extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name = "";

    @LinkingObjects("volleyballPlayer")
    private final RealmResults<Player> players = null;
}
```

Sorting is:

```
RealmResults<VolleyballPlayer> volleyballPlayers = 
  mRealm.where(VolleyballPlayer.class)
  .sort("name") 
  .findAll();
```

Thank you